# Is it possible to setup Grizzly for graceful shutdown?

Tags: java, jersey, nio, grizzly

I have a Jersey application running on embedded Grizzly, that is initialized like the following:

```
HttpServer httpServer = GrizzlyServerFactory.createHttpServer(BASE_URI, rc);
```

What i want to achieve is let the running requests finish when shutting down, but not let new requests in. I couldn't find a way to achieve this through public methods of HttpServer, or not even with private methods and such (although it is not nice, a solution by accessing private stuff through reflection is also ok)

Does anyone know how this is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Grizzly 2.3.4 it is possible; see the post on [Gracefully Terminating a Grizzly Transport](https://web.archive.org/web/20160913220533/http://www.notshabby.net/2013/08/gracefully-terminating-a-grizzly-transport/). In short, implement a [GracefulShutdownListener](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.glassfish.grizzly/grizzly-framework/2.3.28/org/glassfish/grizzly/GracefulShutdownListener.html) registered using [Transport.addShutdownListener()](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.glassfish.grizzly/grizzly-framework/2.3.16/org/glassfish/grizzly/Transport.html#addShutdownListener(org.glassfish.grizzly.GracefulShutdownListener)) upon the implementation-specific transport mechanism (such as `NIOTransport`, `TCPNIOTransport`, or `UDPNIOTransport`).